# Printing new line in Android with for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm new to android development but i have some Java background. In Java when using loop i used `System.out.println();` but in Android after loop finishes, I only get the last result. I'm using JSON data which contains 10 lines.

Here's my code:

```
json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("entries"); // get articles array                

for(int i = 0; i <articles.length(); i++) {
    etResponse.setText(articles.getJSONObject(i).toString());
}
```

`etResponse` is my `EditText` and it only shows last line.

I have also tried:

```
builder.append(String.valueOf(articles.getJSONObject(i).toString()));
```

But it gave no data. 
So my question is how to get all lines data printed, not just the last one?

Comment: **maybe** you forgot this logic . system.out.print() **+** \n = system.out.println(); ... so in normal java , each loop had a \n inbuilt if you used the function with **ln** for printing

Answer (score 0):

use [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
 for (int i = 0; i < articles.length();i++) {
   etResponse.append(... + "\n");
 }
```

Comment: but how do you print only the values inside the JSON object. I have id 1, id 2 .. and so on and name John, name Bruce. So how do i print only those in line  without anny {} [] "", just the values like "1 John Adress 555-555 " ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the StringBuilder to generate the string and then setting the value to etResponse outside the for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `etResponse.setText("new text")` you're swapping the previous value with "new text".

Fix with saving your values in a `StringBuilder` and set them to the `EditText` once you're ready.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0;i <articles.length();i++) {
         long id = articles.getJSONObject(i).getLong("id");
         String name = articles.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
         sb.append(id).append(" -> ").append(name).append("\n);
}

etResponse.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: but how do you print only the values inside the JSON object. I have id 1, id 2 .. and so on and name John, name Bruce. So how do i print only those in line  without anny {} [] "", just the values like "1 John Adress 555-555 " ?

Comment: Edited my answer to include this. Replace "id" and "name" with your keys in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you **overwrite** the current text every time your loop executes. So instead of setting the text in every iteration of the loop (somewhat inefficient to because the GUI gets updated a lot), you can store the text in a `String` variable and after the loop you can update the GUI with `setText()`.

```
String result = "";

for(int i = 0;i <articles.length();i++){
     result += articles.getJSONObject(i).toString() + "\n";
}

etResponse.setText(result);
```

Comment: just to note that it is much better to use StringBuilder if you want to concatenate strings instead of just one String - it is much faster

Comment: Strings concatenation -> 11741 ms
StringBuilder use -> 7 ms 
Take a look at this SO question - there is an example code for evaluating the time -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: but how do you print only the values inside the JSON object. I have id 1, id 2 .. and so on and name John, name Bruce. So how do i print only those without anny {} [] "", just the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your code to this one:

```
json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("entries"); // get articles array                
StringBuilder wholeText = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0;i <articles.length();i++){
   wholeText.append(articles.getJSONObject(i).toString() + "\n");
}
etResponse.setText(wholeText.toString());
```

Comment: but how do you print only the values inside the JSON object. I have id 1, id 2 .. and so on and name John, name Bruce. So how do i print only those in line  without anny {} [] "", just the values like "1 John Adress 555-555 " ?